# Resize the terminal with Python?

Tags: python, terminal

I couldn't find anything with a quick Google search, nor anything on here, saving for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516025/how-to-set-explicitly-the-terminal-size-when-using-pexpect). However, it doesn't do the trick. So how exactly *do* you resize the terminal using Python?

Comment: Oh, right. I'm using a Linux (Ubuntu 10.10, if it matters). And now to display my ignorance: '*nix'?

Comment: hehe no problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix#Branding

Comment: What exactly do you mean by resize? Do you mean the pty/tty knowledge of the terminal size, or an actual terminal application (e.g. xterm) size (geometry)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To change the tty/pty setting you have to use an ioctl on the stdin file descriptor.

```
import termios
import struct
import fcntl

def set_winsize(fd, row, col, xpix=0, ypix=0):
    winsize = struct.pack("HHHH", row, col, xpix, ypix)
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSWINSZ, winsize)
```

But to change the actual window size you can use terminal escape sequences, but not all terminals support or enable that feature. If you're using urxvt you can do this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\x1b[8;{rows};{cols}t".format(rows=32, cols=100))
```

But that may not work on all terminals.

Comment: I can report that this works on Ubuntu's Terminal, but only if the Terminal app window is not maximized.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), you can change the size of the terminal window with something like this:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

id_cmd='xdotool getactivewindow'
resize_cmd='xdotool windowsize --usehints {id} 100 30'

proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(id_cmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
windowid,err=proc.communicate()
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(resize_cmd.format(id=windowid)))
proc.communicate()
```

PS. On Ubuntu `xdotool` is provided by a package of the same name.

Comment: this seems resize x11 gui window, not resize (virtual) terminal window in pty