# How can I explicitly set the terminal size in python?

Tags: python, resize, cross-platform

I would like to explicitly set the terminal size. Is there a cross-platform way to do this?
I want to make a game, showing fixed-sized art.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418678/resize-the-terminal-with-python

Comment: Cross-platform?  Likely not.  What is your use case?

Comment: a game in terminal using ASCII art. Is that even possible?

Comment: I don't know.  Why not use a Tkinter text frame set to a fixed width font?

Comment: Right, I hadn't thought of that at all! I'm still a noob ;)
Thanks, I'll try that out when I have time!

Answer (score 0):

I used Tkinter (Thanks Steven Rumbalski!), because I don't mind using GUI if it's cross-platform. Basically, I set a window geometry and the size of my "art" label:

```
from Tkinter import *

#Assign a variable to the shown image to be able to change it
displayed_image = "test.gif"

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        #Make a frame to enclose the art with a relief
        self.topframe = Frame(master, borderwidth=5, pady=5, relief=RIDGE)
        #Pack the frame to draw it
        self.topframe.pack()

        #This frame will contain the prompt
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        photo = PhotoImage(file="../Art/"+displayed_image)
        art = Label(self.topframe, width=1280, height=720, image=photo)
        art.photo = photo
        art.pack()

        prompt = Entry(self.frame, width=1280)
        prompt.pack()

root = Tk()
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d" % (1300, 780))
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```