# screen get squeezed after pexpect ssh to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, pexpect

I'm using pexpect to a remote server and handover screen to me. the script run success. only problem is that the screen output kind of get squeezed after login using pexpect. it's like not getting a full screen terminal for input and output. the impact is while input command it could cause problem and some content can't be fully displayed.(get a "newline" in the middle of the screen) but i'm sure there's no problem with the screen output by using normal ssh login.

I use Iterm2 for remote login, but whatever Iterm or terminal. issue is the same.

```py
import pexpect
import getpass, os , sys
from time import sleep

def ssh_command (user,password,servername):
    ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l %s %s  '%(user, servername))
    fout = open('mylog.txt','wb')
    child.logfile = fout
    i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, ssh_newkey, 'password: '],timeout =5)
    if i == 0: # Timeout
        print('ERROR!')
        return None
    if i == 1: # SSH does not have the public key. Just accept it.
        child.sendline ('yes')
        child.expect ('password: ')
        i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'password: '],timeout =5)
        if i == 0: # Timeout
            print('ERROR!')
        return None
    child.sendline(password)
    child.interact()
```

expect output(like normal ssh login):

```
Mac:user|/var $ ssh admin101
user@admin101's password:
[user@admin101 ~]$ echo "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890"
```

squeezed terminal output(by using pexpect):

```
Mac:user|/var $ python remote.py
4567890an@admin101 ~]$ echo "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 123
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358807/13317 ?

Comment: @kenster that's awesome ! set the winsize actually solve my problem. you saved my world ! appreciate so much !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the column width of a pexpect ssh session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357149/how-do-i-set-the-column-width-of-a-pexpect-ssh-session)